# UAC elevation via Local Admin "pin auth" not present for Azure AD Joined Windows 11

Tags: windows, azure, group-policy

**Is there any way to elevate via local admin pin in UAC prompt for non-admin Azure AD user on Windows joined to Azure Active Directory by making a change in group policy or registry to achieve desired behavior**

If I login into Windows 11 using local or Microsoft account with "Standard" user and have a local admin present with Pin sign-in configured, then in UAC prompts for "Standard" user I can elevate to admin rights by entering "Pin" instead of password for local admin account

However, if same PC is joined to Azure Active Directory, authentication via Pin in UAC prompt is no longer present for local admin account. Only Azure Active Directory account can be authenticated via pin authentication in UAC prompt.

I initially thought that this was somehow caused by Group Policies I applied to my system but I tested same behavior in Windows 11 Evaluation VM with no custom Group Policies applies.

Also, I am 100% aware that no group policy is applied via Azure AD since organization doesn't have intune subscription.

Comment: You may want to check if the PINLogonProvider registry value is enabled (Disabled=0). Key: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\[clsid]`.

Comment: That didn't seem to help